# How to get the list of files in a directory in a shell script starting and stopping at position?

Tags: unix

i want to write the directories of a folder into a file.

This works fine, but it writes all directories into folders.txt:

```
find /websites/clients -type d | sed -r 's:/tmp/::' > folders.txt
```

Find should start at the next two subdirectories and stop after the 5. subdirectory.

For Example if i have the following structure:

```
/websites/clients/abc/xxx/1/2/3
/websites/clients/abc/xxx/1/2/3/test1
/websites/clients/abc/xxx/1/2/3/test1/yyy
/websites/clients/abc/xxx/1/2/3/test2
/websites/clients/def/xxx/1/2/3
/websites/clients/def/xxx/1/2/3/test1
/websites/clients/def/xxx/1/2/3/test1/yyy
/websites/clients/def/xxx/1/2/3/test2
```

I want to write into the file the following lines:

```
/websites/clients/abc/xxx/1/2/3
/websites/clients/def/xxx/1/2/3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `-mindepth 2 -maxdepth 5` to `find` to limit the depth of directory traversal